# How to load Tensorflow Dataset "Iris" and change the labels into one-hot encode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, iris-dataset

I'm trying to load the "iris" dataset directly from tensorflow datasets and I'm stuck.
I'm use to working with CSVs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data = tfds.load("iris",split='train[:80%]', as_supervised=True)
data = data.batch(10)
features, labels = data
```

I don't know how I'm supposed to separate the features X,y. The labels are in a different tensor from the features, but I don't know how to access them to work with. I'd like to one hot encode the labels and feed them into the model, but I'm stuck here.

The tensorflow docs are sparse with info on how to do this. any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can one-hot your labels within the `.map()` method and `tf.one_hot`, like that:

```
data = data.batch(10).map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, depth=3)))

print(next(iter(data))[1])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Fully-working minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data = tfds.load("iris",split='train[:80%]', as_supervised=True)
data = data.batch(10).map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, depth=3))).repeat()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(data, steps_per_epoch=8, epochs=10)
```

```
Epoch 10/10
1/8 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8848 - cat_acc: 0.6000
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8549 - cat_acc: 0.5250
```

Comment: beautiful. that explains it. i didn't fully understand the map function and purpose. thank you.

Comment: hmm, has something changed? When I do that I get `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Comment: @Olli what Tensorflow version do you have? It still works for me for `tf == 2.3` and `tfds == 4.3`

Comment: @NicolasGervais tensorflow 2.4 it also still works, my fault was not setting as_supervised = True which returned a feature dictionary instead. Apologies for the confusion!